# Message library

Tags: swift, parse-platform

The scenario is: **some user sending messages to some group of people**.

I was thinking to create one ROW for that specific conversation into one CLASS. WHERE in that ROW contains information such "sender name", "receiver " and addition I have column (PFRelation) which connects  this specific row to another class where all messages from the user to the receiver would be saved(vice-versa) into.

**So this action will happen every time the user starts a new conversation.**

**The benefit from this prospective :**

Privacy because the only convo that is being saved are only from the user and the receiver group.

**Downside of this prospective:**

We all know that parse only provide 30reqs/s for free which means that 1 min =1800 reqs. So every time I create a new class to keep track of the convo. Am I using a lot of requests ?

I am looking suggestions and thoughts for the ideal way before I implement this messenger library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have come up with something that is similar to what I have used before to implement messaging in an app with Parse as a backend. It's also important to think about how your UI will be querying for data. In general, it's most important to ensure that it is very easy and fast to read data. For most social apps, the following quote from [Facebook's engineering team on Haystack](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Beaver.pdf) is particularly relevant.

> Haystack is an object store that we designed for sharing photos on
>   Facebook where data is written once, read often, never modified, and
>   rarely deleted.

The crucial piece of information here is ***written once, read often, never modified, and rarely deleted***. No matter what approach you decide to take, keep that in mind while engineering your solution. The approach that I have used before to implement a messaging system using Parse is described below.

---

### Overview

Each row (object) of the `Message` class corresponds with an individual text, picture, or video message that was posted. Each `Message` belongs to a `Group`. A `Group` can be as small as 2 `User` (private conversation) or grow as large as you like.

The `RecentMessage` class is the solution I came up with to deal with quickly and easily populating the UI. Each `RecentMessage` object corresponds to each `Group` that a given `User` may belong. Each `User` in a `Group` will have their own `RecentMessage` object which is kept up to date using [beforeSave/afterSave cloud code triggers](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers). Whenever a new `Message` is created, in the afterSave trigger we want to update all of the `RecentMessage` objects that belong to the `Group`.

You will most likely have a table in your app which displays all of the conversations that the user is part of. This is easily achieved by querying for all of that user's `RecentMessage` objects which already contains all of the `Group` information needed to load the rest of the messages when selected and also contains the most recent message's data (hence the name) to display in the table. Alternatively, `RecentMessage` could contain a pointer to the most recent `Message`, however I decided that copying the data was a beneficial tradeoff since it streamlines future queries.

### Message

- group (pointer to group which message is part of)
- user (pointer to user who created it)
- text (string)
- picture (optional file)
- video (optional file)

### RecentMessage

- group (group pointer)
- user (user pointer)
- lastMessage (string containing the text of most recent `Message`)
- lastUser (pointer to the `User` who posted the most recent `Message`)

### Group

- members (array of user pointers)
- name or whatever other info you want

---

### Security/Privacy

Security and privacy are imperative when creating messaging functionality in your app. Make sure to read through the Parse Engineering security blog posts, and take your time to let it all soak in: [Part I](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/), [Part II](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-ii-class-hysteria/), [Part III](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iii-are-you-on-the-list/), [Part IV](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iv-ahead-in-the-cloud/), [Part V](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-v-how-to-make-friends/).

Most important in our case is Part III which describes ACLs, or [Access Control Lists](http://blog.parse.com/learn/get-off-my-lawn-a-new-way-to-control-access-to-your-app/). `Group` objects will have an ACL which corresponds to all of its member `User`. `RecentMessage` objects will have a restricted read/write ACL to its owner `User`. `Message` objects will inherit the ACL of the `Group` to which they belong, allowing all of the `Group` members to read. I recommend disabling the write ACL in the afterSave trigger so messages cannot be modified.

---

### General Remarks

With regards to Parse and the request limit, you need to accept that fact that you will very quickly surpass the 30 req/s free tier. As a general rule of thumb, it's much better to focus on building the best possible user experience than to focus too much on scalability. By and large, issues of scalability rarely come into play because most apps fail. Not saying that to be discouraging — just something to keep in mind to prevent you from falling into the trap of over-engineering at the cost of time :)

Comment: First Question:  `Message` class is being used as a template where the first message get saved right? and `RecentMessage` is being used as extender to save the rest of conversation. However do you need to link them and a way, for example what if we're querying all the message i believed so far i would only get the latest message

Comment: Nope, the `Message` class contains every text, photo, or video message that is part of every `Group`. The `Message` class is the literal message being sent. `RecentMessage` is simply used as a container of sorts, to make it very fast and efficient to display the most recent `Message` from each of the `Group` that a `User` is a part of.

Comment: For example, you could have a TableView which displays all of the conversations that a user is a part of. To do this, you would query for all of the `RecentMessage` objects which belong to that user. Then you can populate the table cells with data such as the most recent message and who said it.

Comment: This approach also allows you to easily load the rest of the conversation. Once a `RecentMessage` object is selected in that table, you can segue to new view controller to display all of that group's messages. All you will need to do is query the `Message` class for all objects which belong to the same `Group` as the selected `RecentMessage`